# Javascript/JQuery .animate() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a sliding image gallery where every interval they will slide along and the first image will fade out and the new image will fade in. The fading in and out is working and my images are set as 'position: absolute', but they won't slide. I set up a jsfiddle so you can see what's happening:

http://jsfiddle.net/9awwF/

The HTML code:

```
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">

    <p id="discoImg1a"><a href="includes/images/discoImg1.png">
        <img src="http://edubuzz.org/lawprimaryp6/files/2011/11/250px-Disco_ball41.jpg" alt="img1" width="200" height="200" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1"/></a></p>

    <p id="discoImg2a"><a href="includes/images/discoImg2.png">
        <img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1005534/1272/v/950/depositphotos_12726061-Glass-Circle-Color-Disco-Ball.jpg" alt="img1" width="200" height="200" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 250px; z-index: 1"/></a></p>

    <p id="discoImg3a"><a href="includes/images/discoImg3.png">
        <img src="http://fivestaralaska.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/disco1.jpeg" alt="img1" width="200" height="200" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 500px; z-index: 1"/></a></p>

    <p id="discoImg4a"><a href="includes/images/discoImg4.png">
        <img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1005534/1272/v/950/depositphotos_12726061-Glass-Circle-Color-Disco-Ball.jpg" alt="img1" width="200" height="200" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 750px; z-index: 1"/></a></p>

    <p id="discoImg5a"><a href="includes/images/discoImg5.png">
        <img src="http://www.djjdee-mobiledisco.co.uk/images/disco.jpg" alt="img1" width="200" height="200" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 1000px; z-index: 1"/></a></p>

    <p id="discoImg6a"><a href="includes/images/discoImg6.png">
        <img src="http://www.djjdee-mobiledisco.co.uk/images/party.jpg" alt="img1" width="200" height="200" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 1250px; z-index: 1"/></a></p>

    <p id="discoImg7a"><a href="includes/images/discoImg7.png">
        <img src="http://www.djjdee-mobiledisco.co.uk/images/karaoke.gif" alt="img1" width="200" height="200" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 1500px; z-index: 1"/></a></p>

    <p id="discoImg8a"><a href="includes/images/discoImg8.png">
        <img src="http://www.djjdee-mobiledisco.co.uk/images/discolights.jpg" alt="img1" width="200" height="200" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 1750px; z-index: 1"/></a></p>

    <p id="discoImg9a"><a href="includes/images/discoImg9.png">
        <img src="http://www.armagh.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Trad-Disco.jpg" alt="img1" width="200" height="200" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 2000px; z-index: 1"/></a></p>

</div>

</body>
```

The script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#discoImg6a").hide();
        $("#discoImg7a").hide();
        $("#discoImg8a").hide();
        $("#discoImg9a").hide();

        var currentFirstSlide = 1;
        var maxSlides = 9;

        function updateSlides() {
            // Fade out the first image shown                
            $("#discoImg" + currentFirstSlide + "a").fadeOut(3000);

            // Go through every image and move them to the left by 250px
            for (var x = 1; x < 10; x++) {
                var left = $("#discoImg" + x + "a").position().left;
                $("#discoImg" + x + "a").animate({ left: left - 250 + 'px' });
            }

            // Calculate which slide the new one will be and fade it in
            var newSlide = currentFirstSlide + 5;
            if (newSlide > maxSlides) { newSlide = 1; }
            $("#discoImg" + newSlide + "a").fadeIn(3000);

            // Increment the current first slide ready for the next update
            currentFirstSlide++;
            if (currentFirstSlide > maxSlides) { currentFirstSlide = 1; }
       }

        // Move the slides every 3.5s
        setInterval(function () { updateSlides() }, 3500);

    });
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're animating the `left` property of the `p` element, but it has a default `position` of static, so this doesn't do anything. You should either animate `left` on the `img` element or give absolute or relative positioning to the `p` element.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `p` element has the `id`, not the `img`

```
<p><a href="includes/images/discoImg1.png">
<img id="discoImg1a" src="..."  style="position: absolute; ..."/></a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no effect with property **left** without position absolute or fixed.

Answer (score 0):

On your `css` try giving that `absolute` positions a `left: 0px;` may be it's going to slide automatically, and don't forget to give it a `relative` container.